# Android Listview search Json

Tags: android, json, listview, search

I have a problem. I want to search my listview with SearchView or EditText and filter my Items if someone type some Text. But i don´t find the correct answere here because my json file comes from a php / mysql database. Can Someone help me ?

Here is my Code

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity  implements ListView.OnItemClickListener {
private ListView listView;
private String JSON_STRING;
EditText et;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
    listView.setOnItemClickListener(this);
    listView.smoothScrollToPosition(0);
    listView.setTextFilterEnabled(true);
    et = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
    getJSON();

    }

private void showEmployee() {
    JSONObject jsonObject = null;
    final ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> list = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
    try {
        jsonObject = new JSONObject(JSON_STRING);
        final JSONArray result = jsonObject.getJSONArray(Config.TAG_JSON_ARRAY);

        for (int i = 0; i < result.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject jo = result.getJSONObject(i);
            String id = jo.getString(Config.TAG_ID);
            String kfz = jo.getString(Config.TAG_KFZ);
            String bland = jo.getString(Config.TAG_BLAND);
            String kreis = jo.getString(Config.TAG_KREIS);

            HashMap<String, String> employees = new HashMap<>();
            employees.put(Config.TAG_ID, id);
            employees.put(Config.TAG_KFZ, kfz);
            employees.put(Config.TAG_BLAND, bland);
            employees.put(Config.TAG_KREIS, kreis);
            list.add(employees);
        }


    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    final ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
            MainActivity.this, list, R.layout.list_item,
            new String[]{Config.TAG_KFZ, Config.TAG_KREIS},
            new int[]{R.id.kfz, R.id.kreis});

    listView.setAdapter(adapter);


}

private void getJSON(){
    class GetJSON extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,String> {

        ProgressDialog loading;
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            loading = ProgressDialog.show(MainActivity.this,"Suche KFZ Kennzeichen","Warten...",false,false);

        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
            super.onPostExecute(s);
            loading.dismiss();
            JSON_STRING = s;
            showEmployee();
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
            RequestHandler rh = new RequestHandler();
            String s = rh.sendGetRequest(Config.URL_GET_ALL);

            return s;
        }
    }
    GetJSON gj = new GetJSON();
    gj.execute();
}

@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, KfzDetails.class);
    HashMap<String,String> map =(HashMap)parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
    String kfzid = map.get(Config.TAG_ID).toString();
    intent.putExtra(Config.EMP_ID,kfzid);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Oh i found a Solution for SimpleAdapter,

SimpleAdapter mAdapter;   // at first

than

```
final SimpleAdapter mAdapter =  new SimpleAdapter(
            MainActivity.this,list, R.layout.list_item,
            new String[]{Config.TAG_KFZ, Config.TAG_KREIS},
            new int[]{R.id.kfz, R.id.kreis});

    listView.setAdapter(mAdapter);

    et.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            mAdapter.getFilter().filter(s);

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

        }
    });
```

The Filter runs but it duplicate my entries 
How can i fix that, or better , how can i only search for KFZ and not for Kreis

Comment: this is how `SimpleAdapter` implement its `Filter`, as i said, you need to use a different `Adapter`, try some custom adapter like: `class Adapter extends` [MatchableArrayAdapter](https://gist.github.com/pskink/2dd4d17a93caf02ff696533e82f952b0)`<YourItemDataModel> { ...` and override its `onBind` and `matches` method